# python panda count occurence in matrice column

Tags: python, pandas

I wouldike to display at the end with the number of value "Présent". Here an image to describe what I want : [image: Example]

I use panda to display this matrice and this structure :

```
def create_rapport(self, name_file, data,  column_name, all_intersection):

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(name_file[:-4] + ".xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=data.keys(), columns=column_name)
    data_key = list(data.keys())
    for elem in data_key:
        for i, subelem in enumerate(all_intersection, 1):
            if elem in subelem:
                df.loc[elem, column_name[i]] = "Présent"

    df.loc[:, column_name[0]] = data.values()
    df.to_excel(writer)
    print(df)
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare values by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), count `True`s by `sum` and last convert to integers with assign to new row by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc['Total'] = df.eq('Présent').sum().astype(int)
```